# Trying to find max value from a list of values generated from a loop

Tags: python, list, loops, max

I am really new to python and have been working on this with the help of others.
I am trying to figure out the right way to go about finding the max of the list acct_all_total.
Everything else works if I remove the part w/ the max function.
erros i get: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.
Or I get 0 as a result.

```
    def inventory(info, months_subscribed, add_free_months, video_on_demand):
        acct_all_total = 0
        acct_max = 0
         # here you init the total value to 0
        if info.get('months_subscribed') == 3:
            months_subscribed_total = info.get('months_subscribed') * 18
        elif info.get('months_subscribed') < 3:
            months_subscribed_total = info['months_subscribed'] * 7
        elif info.get('months_subscribed') > 3:
            months_subscribed_total = info['months_subscribed'] - 3 * 7 + 18
    
        print(f"User {info.get('name')} has months subscribed total of : $ {months_subscribed_total} ")
    
        if info['ad_free_months'] > 0:
            ad_free_total = info.get('ad_free_months') * 2
            print(f" User {info.get('name')} total ad free is : $ {ad_free_total} ")
    
        if info['video_on_demand'] > 0:
            video_on_demand_total = info.get('video_on_demand') * 27.99
    
            print(f" User {info.get('name')} total video on demand is $ : {video_on_demand_total} ")
    
            acct_all_total = int(months_subscribed_total + ad_free_total + video_on_demand_total)
            # acct_all_total = [int(acct_all_total)] 
            print(f"Total for {info.get('name')} is: {acct_all_total} ")
    
            # acct_max = (max(acct_all_total)) #if I use these hashtag parts I get the type error mentioned above.
        
        # if int(acct_all_total) >  int(acct_all_total):
        #     acct_max = int(acct_all_total)
        #     print(f" User {info.get('name')} max value is: {acct_max} ")
    
    
    
        
        return acct_all_total ; acct_max
        
    
    acct_info = [{'name': 'acct_1', 'months_subscribed': 2, 'ad_free_months': 3, 'video_on_demand': 1},
                 {'name': 'acct_2', 'months_subscribed': 1, 'ad_free_months': 2, 'video_on_demand': 2},
                 {'name': 'acct_3', 'months_subscribed': 2, 'ad_free_months': 1, 'video_on_demand': 3}]
    
    acct_max = 0
    combined_total = 0
    months_subscribed = 0
    ad_free_months = 0
    video_on_demand = 0
    months_subscribed_total = 0
    ad_free_total = 0
    video_on_demand_total = 0
    acct_all_total = 0
    for acct in acct_info:
        print("--")
        acct_all_total+=inventory(acct, months_subscribed, ad_free_months, video_on_demand)
    for acct in acct_info: #when I try it this way I get 0 as a result
  if int(acct_all_total) >  int(acct_all_total):
    acct_max = acct_all_total
         
    print("Total for all accounts:",acct_all_total)
```

Example of Output:

```
User acct_1 has months subscribed total of : $ 14 
 User acct_1 total ad free is : $ 6 
 User acct_1 total video on demand is $ : 27.99 
Total for acct_1 is: 47 
--
User acct_2 has months subscribed total of : $ 7 
 User acct_2 total ad free is : $ 4 
 User acct_2 total video on demand is $ : 55.98 
Total for acct_2 is: 66 
--
User acct_3 has months subscribed total of : $ 14 
 User acct_3 total ad free is : $ 2 
 User acct_3 total video on demand is $ : 83.97 
Total for acct_3 is: 99 
Total for all accounts: 212
0
```

Comment: The question definition seems ambiguous could you provide what's inside the variable acct_all_total

Comment: You don't understand what you are doing. `acct_max = (max(acct_all_total))` - this is essentially saying "find the maximum of this number`. What is a maximum of a number? What's the maximum of 50? Or maximum of 11? Define what you are trying to accomplish, then try to do it.

Comment: The acct_all_total was created to print out the totals for each account … I’m trying to find the largest of those totals … if that makes sense ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the biggest number in a list you can sort it first and then get the first or last item in the list.

```py
obj = [1, 6, 9, 123, 64, 12]
obj.sort()        # Sorts the list into this: [1, 6, 9, 12, 64, 123]
print(obj[-1])    # [-1] Returns the last item in the list
```

Make sure the list does not contain strings as the sort function will not sort strings mixed with integers or floats.

Note that your "acct_all_total" is not a list, a list is defined with [] (insert a reference to docs or other basic explanation).

Edit:
I would like to clarify that you're probably better off researching a bit more about the different types of objects there are in python, how to use them and when to use which one.